# Is there a way to add fields to all documents in firebase - my new registration system includes firstname and last name?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i’m getting the obvious error of undefined name

```
CloudNote.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
firstName = snapshot.data()[firstNameFieldName] as String;
lastName = snapshot.data()[lastNameFieldName] as String;
```

I know the painful option of manually adding the field but…..last resort.

Strange that the Firestore Database doesn’t allow you to select all documents in your collection and add fields to all of them.

Comment: My friend, if you could add a field to all documents in a collection, what would you assign to them `firstName = Bob`? Do you know that you can have one collection with documents, and you can run Twitter app on it? You can push there user data/settings/posts...

Comment: Ok, what would you suggest? It could be empty for now, i'm not using the data currently. I just want to have the field for when I add a profile page. They can add the name if they wish. I've just expanded from a note taking app, it wasn't designed for anything complex.

Comment: Yeah we have null safety on dart now :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 Future<void> addFirstNameLastName(
  {required String ownerUserId,
  required String firstName,
  required String lastName}) async {
try {
  await notes
      .where(
        ownerUserIdFieldName,
        isEqualTo: ownerUserId,
      )
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((doc) {
            doc.reference.update({
              firstNameFieldName: firstName,
              lastNameFieldName: lastName,
            });
          }));
} catch (e) {
}}
```

That's a good point, I think Firebase/Google are working on that feature. It is a little odd that they have only implemented delete functionality. But try the code above in your FirebaseCloudStorage class. Assign it to a button

Comment: I dont think updating the firstNameFieldName is the way to go. Think I have to use set

Comment: @ArvinT Using set instead of update, you will override the whole document with data you pass to set method, but you have too option to use set and not override data to do that use option `{merge: true}` in set method.

Comment: Thank you @Mises, i'll make sure to add that

Comment: @Mises, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It helped a lot

Comment: @Mises I don't think that's the point of StackOverflow,  it's not a popularity contest xD
I've learnt from archived posts before.  The points mean nothing if you care about actually learning.  Regardless Dziękuję, przyjacielu

Comment: You could always upvote ;) I think the people at Firebase don't like me very much. I should remove the firebase tag

Comment: Or use it as a good example of what not to do. Which is how I figured out the answer, I wouldnt have done that successfully without your {merge:true} comment. I also watched the firebase data video on the firebase docs website. Which said the same thing. So your comment + more research actually helped find the solution. If you upload an answer I can give you your accepted solution points. @Mises

Comment: @ArvinT Nope, thanks, I'm not helping only for points.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addFirstNameLastName(
  {required String ownerUserId,
  required String? firstName,
  required String? lastName}) async {
try {
  await notes
      .where(
        ownerUserIdFieldName,
        isEqualTo: ownerUserId,
      )
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((doc) {
            doc.reference.set({
              firstNameFieldName: '',
              lastNameFieldName: '',
            }, SetOptions(merge: true));
          }));
} catch (e) {
  throw (CouldNotGetAllNotesException());
}}
```

Adding a - update function in FirebaseCloudStorage class

---

Calling the class when button is tapped.